# TYPO3 HTACCESS | changing HTTPS to HTTP in url redirects me to the root page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

When I change my url from **https**://www.example.com/company/ to **http**://www.example.com/company/ 
I get redirected to the root page instead of it changing HTTP to HTTPS. **What am I missing?**

Here is my HTACCESS file, I am using a TYPO3 CMS 7.6.19

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Obvious question first: why do you redirect from the secure HTTPS to the insecure HTTP?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala I am not, the problem is if there is a link like this for example: HTTP:// http://www.example.com/company/ then the user would get redirected to the rootpage. That is the problem.

Comment: I've seen a webprojekt, where editors had embeded HTTP iframes, wich requires, that such page self is insecure. Sadly, but was a usecase...

Comment: @jokumer not sure how this is connected to my problem? English is not my first language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default .htaccess file for TYPO3 does some rewriting of its own. If you place this below at the bottom of that file, it will first execute the default rules. This will mess up your redirect. You should add these redirect rules above the default TYPO3 rewrite rules, so just below the existing `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: I removed the cache just in case and used Edge and Firefox but I still get redirected to the root page.

Comment: I just tested your .htaccess exactly and it works fine. Are you sure there's no other redirect? If you remove the .htaccess, does it still redirect?

Comment: No it does not redirect afterwards.

Comment: Is there anything else in your .htaccess?

Comment: Just comments and basic settings which were generated by TYPO3

Comment: Is this above or below the things that are in the default .htaccess for TYPO3?

Comment: It is below under a comment saying : # Add your own rules here.

Comment: The default TYPO3 .htaccess has its own rewrite rules. This probably messes up your rewrite. I've edited my answer

Comment: Let me try it out